# Selecting combination with a fixed column in R

Tags: r, combinations, combn

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
 aa   bb      
 --------
 a    1   
 a    2   
 a    3   
 b    4       
 b    5    
 b    1
```

I want above data frame to have a pair of elements picked from 'bb' and look like the below frame

```
 aa   bb   cc   
 -------------
 a    1    2   
 a    1    3   
 a    2    3   
 b    4    5  
 b    4    1   
 b    5    1
```

R input code

```
d1 <- read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ";", text = 
"aa;bb
 a;1   
 a;2   
 a;3   
 b;4       
 b;5    
 b;1"   )
```

Comment: Please explain the logic behind column "cc" in more detail

Comment: I guess this should get you the result `library(data.table);setDT(d1)[,{tmp <- combn(bb,2); list(bb= tmp[1,], cc= tmp[2,]) } , by = aa]` (based on @Ananda Mahto's comments

Answer (score 4):

Using @Ananda Mahto's generous comments about the `combn`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d1)`), grouped by 'aa', we get the pairwise combinations of 'bb' (`combn(bb,2)`), extract the rows from it to create the 'bb' and 'cc'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)[,{tmp <- combn(bb,2)
           list(bb= tmp[1,], cc= tmp[2,]) } , by = aa]
#   aa bb cc
#1:  a  1  2
#2:  a  1  3
#3:  a  2  3
#4:  b  4  5
#5:  b  4  1
#6:  b  5  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

d1 %>% group_by(aa) %>%
       do(data.frame(t(combn(.[["bb"]], 2))))

Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: aa [2]

                  aa    X1    X2
              (fctr) (dbl) (dbl)
1                  a     1     2
2                  a     1     3
3                  a     2     3
4                  b     4     5
5                  b     4     1
6                  b     5     1
```

Comment: Thanx @jeremycg, I have used your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Only base R.

```
d2 <- t(do.call(cbind, tapply(d1$bb, d1$aa, function(x)combn(x, 2))))
rownames(d2) <- d1$aa
d2
#   [,1] [,2]
# a    1    2
# a    1    3
# a    2    3
# b    4    5
# b    4    1
# b    5    1
```

Comment: I also thought of similar solution as well but thanx for the answer.